# ¿Cómo eliminar elementos específicos de una cadena?

Tags: javascript

Me piden eliminar las letras 'x', 'y', 'z' de una cadena dada, en caso no tenga esas letras retornar la misma cadena, por ejemplo:

```
var cadena = 'jsdkxsjuewyidiktqwzmn';
var stringArray = cadena.split('')//['j', 's', 'd', 'k', 'x', 's', 'j', 'u', 'e', 'w', 'y', 'i', 'd', 'i', 'k', 't', 'q', 'w', 'z', 'm', 'n']
stringArray = stringArray.filter((i) => i !== 'x'); // filtro 'x'
stringArray = stringArray.filter((i) => i !== 'y'); // filtro 'y'
stringArray = stringArray.filter((i) => i !== 'z'); // filtro 'z'
var resp = stringArray.join('');
console.log(resp);// 'jsdksjuewidiktqwmn'
```

Sé que esta no es la forma correcta de hacerlo pero lo intenté con un bucle `for` utilizando el operador `or` y no llegue a una solución, así que lo intenté con filter y el operador `or` pero solo filtra la primera letra 'x'. Solo lo he logrado de esta forma que no es la óptima, me parece que tal vez lo mejor sea con un `for()` pero no he conseguido una resolución al problema (ya busqué documentación en español e inglés pero nada)... Debe haber una solución con un bucle `for`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay varias formas.

De la forma que tu lo tienes se podría mejorar la eficacia si concatenas las condiciones del `filter`

```js
var cadena = 'jsdkxsjuewyidiktqwzmn';
var stringArray = cadena.split('')//['j', 's', 'a', 'k', 's', 'j', 'u', 'e', 'b', 'i', 'd', 'i', 'k', 'c', 'q', 'w', 'm', 'n']
stringArray = stringArray.filter((i) => !['x', 'y', 'z'].includes(i)); 
var resp = stringArray.join('');
console.log(resp);// 'jsdksjuewidiktqwmn'
```

Otra opción es usando `replace`

```js
var cadena = 'jsdkxsjuewyidiktqwzmn';

cadena = cadena.replace('x', '') // filtro 'x'
  .replace('y', '') // filtro 'y'
  .replace('z', '') // filtro 'z'
console.log(cadena);// 'jsdksjuewidiktqwmn'
```

O puedes hacerlo con expresiones regulares.

```js
var cadena = 'jsdkxsjuewyidiktqwzmn';

cadena = cadena.replace(/[xyz]/g,'');
console.log(cadena);// 'jsdksjuewidiktqwmn'
```

Comment: la primera forma era la que estaba tratando de conseguir, tengo solo una duda y es que esta forma de concatenacion !['x', 'y', 'z'] solo es valido para filter y todos los metodos de los arrays o tambien se podria usar esa concatenacion en un for?

Comment: simplemente es un array `['x', 'y', 'z']` es como si creara `my_array` y con `includes` verifico si dicho elemento está en el array, `mi_array= ['x', 'y', 'z'] ` y luego `my_array.includes('x')` eso me va a devolver `true` dado que el array si contiene ese elemento